# Bootstrap using fluid grid vs standard grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have a basic Bootstrap question regarding the grid system. When you use the standard grid and apply the container class your container width ends up being 940px by default. If I want my container to be larger do I then use the fluid grid system so my span classes expand to fill the entire container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a *standard grid*, the container, row and spans sizes are fixed (in pixels) and with a fluid grid that sizes are dynamic (in percentages).

As you said, container width is 940px by default in standard grid and 100% in fluid grid. It's not necessary to use fluid grid just to make your container larger, that depends of on your needs (if you need your design to be responsive or not). An easy solutions is just to override the width value of container class (.container) after the inclusion of bootstrap.css file.

```
.container {
  width: 1024px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Also need to override span widths!

Comment: Would I still need to use the class "row-fluid" or if I just use "row" do the span classes adjust based on the container size?

Comment: `SpanX` sizes are fixed. My suggestion is to use container-fluid and row-fluid. If you don't want your container-fluid width to be 100%, override it (e.g. width: 1024px) and span classes can adjust.

Comment: Perfect that is what I expected the behavior to be I just wanted to confirm that. Thanks for the help.